# Is there a way to update the inverse of a sum of two matrices following a rescaling of one of them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ (let's assume that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible, as is their sum), and a scalar $g$.

I am interested in the matrix

$$M^{-1} = (A + gB)^{-1}$$

[I am aware of various expressions for computing this inverse in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices), but I am interested in whether, if I calculate $M^{-1}$ for some value of $g$, is there a way to quickly update $M^{-1}$ following an update to the value of $g$?

I am specifically interested in whether this can be done without performing any additional inversions after updating $g$, i.e. if I can just store $A$, $B$, $A^{-1}$, $B^{-1}$ (or some factorizations of them) and the previous value of $g$ in memory, and then somehow update $M^{-1}$ as a function of these?

I've just found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670649/efficient-diagonal-update-of-matrix-inverse), which suggests a solution if $B=I$, but I fear I may be out of luck for the more general case where $B\neq I$. I would also potentially be interested in solutions which rely on sparsity of either $A$ or $B$, as I may have some cases in which this is true.

Comment: You can use the following : $(A + gB)^{-1} = ((AB^{-1} + gI)B)^{-1} = B^{-1} (AB^{-1} + gI)^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, that does look handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so for completeness: per the comment from deb above, we can do:

$$(A+gB)^{-1} = B^{-1}(AB^{-1} + gI)^{-1}$$

and let
$$AB^{-1}=PDP^{-1}$$
where $P$ gives the eigenvectors and $D$ the eigenvalues of $C=AB^{-1}$, which allows us to apply [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670649/efficient-diagonal-update-of-matrix-inverse) to get

$$(A+gB)^{-1} =B^{-1}P(D + gI)^{-1}P^{-1}$$

$P$ and $B^{-1}P$ can be pre-computed once, and $(D+gI)^{-1}$ is easy to invert quickly because it is diagonal. Neat!