# Inverse of matrix after updating diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a real symmetric positive-definite matrix, with known inverse $A^{-1}$. Is there an efficient algorithm to compute $(A+R)^{-1}$, where $R$ is a real diagonal matrix? Assume that $A+R$ is also positive-definite.

**Failed idea with Cholesky decomposition**

I have read about the Cholesky decomposition and how it can be updated efficiently when the matrix changes by a rank-one modification. Since adding $R$ is the same as many rank-one modifications (one for each entry in the diagonal), in principle I could use this algoritm to compute the updated Cholesky decomposition. However this turns out to be $O(n^3)$ (where $n$ is the dimension of the matrices), no better than matrix inversion, because each rank-one update of the Cholesky decomposition is $O(n^2)$, and there are $n$ entries in the diagonal.

**Related**

This is closely related to [Efficient diagonal update of matrix inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/670649/10063). However in that question, the diagonal update is homogeneous. Here the diagonal entries $R_{nn}$ are in principle distinct for each $n$.

Comment: The answer is NO. cf. my answer in  your reference "Efficient diagonal update of matrix inverse".

Comment: Is the answer still no if $A$ is also Toeplitz and we could use the FFT? (I realize this is a slightly different question, I'm still searching to see if it is answered on this site)

Comment: Edit: *circulant, not Toeplitz.